# The factor theorem for vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The factor theorem for groups is the following:

> Let $f:G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism of groups and let $\pi:G\rightarrow G/N$ be the natural map (mapping $g\mapsto gN$), where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in the kernel of $f$. Then there exists a unique homomorphism $\bar{f}:G/N\rightarrow H$ such that $\bar{f}\circ\pi=f$.

I would like to "translate" this to vector spaces. My idea:

> Let $f:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear map between vector spaces and let $V'$ be a subspace of $V$ such that $V'\subseteq\operatorname{ker}f$. Let $\pi:V\rightarrow V/V'$ be the natural homomorphism (mapping $v\mapsto v+V'$). Then there exists a unique linear map $\bar{f}:V/V'\rightarrow W$ such that $\bar{f}\circ\pi=f$.

If $\bar{f}$ exists, then it must be the function defined by $\bar{f}(v+V')=f(v)$. It is simple to show that this function is well-defined and that it is linear with respect to addition. However, I am not able to show that it is linear with respect to scalar multiplication. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a scalar, $\overline f(\lambda v+V')=f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v)=\lambda\overline f(v+V')$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalar multiplication in the quotient space is defined as $\lambda (v+V')=\lambda v+V'$. So it all follows by definition:

$$\begin{align}
\bar{f}(\lambda(v+V'))&=\bar{f}(\lambda v+V')\\
&=f(\lambda v)\\
&=\lambda f(v)\\
&=\lambda\bar{f}(v+V').
\end{align}$$

By the way, in the case of groups you forgot to add the assumption that $N$ is contained in the kernel of $f$.

Comment: I tried to look online for the relation $\lambda(v+V')=\lambda v+V'$ but I couldn't seem to find it. Thank you solving this doubt.

Comment: @Jacob Obviously, in order to work with a quotient space, you first need to know its definition. (including the definition of the operations)